# Oracle Managed Data Access - How to configure TNS_ADMIN dynamically in code?

Tags: asp.net, oracle-manageddataaccess

Is there a way to set or change the TNS_ADMIN setting though code?  This question was asked here by someone else but not answered.

[Put settings in code - Oracle Managed Data Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48208582/put-settings-in-code-oracle-managed-data-access/)

Comment: Why do you need to do this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I think this is it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53345670/change-app-config-programmatically-at-the-runtime

Comment: That doesn't explain *why* you're wanting to do this.